# Why addTarget does not get removed in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5, mpremotecommandcenter

The target of `nextTrackCommand` is called multiple times when I navigate back from a screen and enter the screen again even tho i remove the target in `viewWillDisappear`. What did I do wrong?

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()

    MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared().nextTrackCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] (_) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
        print("go to next track")
        return .success
    }
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared().nextTrackCommand.removeTarget(self)
}
```

Comment: Note that `viewWillDisappear` doesn't necessary mean the end of a VC's life. The VC could appear again after disappearing. Your current code will cause the target to stay removed when the view reappears. I don't know if that's intentional or not...

Comment: @Sweeper yep thank you. I moved it to `viewDidDisappear`

Comment: `viewDidDisappear` would not help here. @Sweeper wanted to help you with the case when you're not going back from `CurrentVC` but instead you are going forward to some `NextVC`. In this case `viewWillDisappear/viewDidDisappear` will be triggered for `CurrentVC` and it will be unsubscribed. In order to fix that you can move your `addTarget` subscription from `viewDidLoad` to `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: @Legonaftik yes I am using viewDidDisappear and viewDidAppear

Comment: @SwiftiSwift No, you are not. You are using `viewDidDisappear` and `viewDidLoad`. Those are not a matching pair.

Comment: @matt i am using it in my own code bro

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The overload of [`addTarget`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpremotecommand/1622910-addtarget) that you are calling doesn't add `self` as the target. It adds an `NSObject` object that you didn't know about before as the target. *It returns this object*. So if you want to remove it, you should get its return value, hold it in a property, so that you can pass it to `removeTarget`.

> Call the `addTarget(handler:)` method to add a block to be called. Remove the handler by calling the `removeTarget(_:)` method, passing in the object returned by this method.

```
var target: NSObject?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()

    target = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared().nextTrackCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] (_) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
        print("go to next track")
        return .success
    }
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared().nextTrackCommand.removeTarget(target)
}
```

Or, call the [other overload](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpremotecommand/1622895-addtarget) that actually allows you to add `self` as a target.

Comment: Well spotted, nice one.

Comment: As matt says, good answer. (Voted). `addTarget(handler:)` seems like a poorly named method. It suggests that it's using target/action, but it takes a block and returns a command handler object. Nothing target/action about that!